# Anyone got a copy of MSIINV.EXE?

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation

Does anyone have a copy of MSIINV.EXE (The MSI Inventory tool)? The site where it used to be available is down(http://www.huydao.net/). I'm trying to uninstall some components in order to force the Visual Studio Setup to reinstall them. I apologize as this is not strictly a programming question but I figured anyone that has installed some of the Visual Studio beta stuff may have run into this problem as well.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a GitHub repository with both the original source and a copy of the .exe for MsiInv.exe.  I am the original author.

https://github.com/ZisBoom/MsiInv.exe

My most common usage is `msiinv.exe -p` to list all installed products, 
or `msiinv.exe -p | findstr /i <pattern>` to find a specific product.
`msiinv.exe -p <leading match>` requires you to know the "startswith" name of the product, whereas findstr is useful for substring.

Command line options:

```
msiinv.exe -?
Usage: msiinv.exe [option [option]]
    -p [product]    Product list
    -f      Feature state by product. (includes -p)
    -q      Component count by product (includes -p)
    -#      Component count and features states by product (-p -f -q)

    -x      Orphaned components.
    -m      Shared components.
    -c      Evaluate components (-x -m).

    -l      List of log files.

    -t      Elapsed time for run. (Benchmarking)

    -s      Reduced output.(-p -#)
    -n      Normal output. (default)
    -v      Verbose output. (default + feature and component lists)
```

Comment: https://github.com/ZisBoom/msiinv.exe  is still valid and likely best long-term location to get (or even rebuild and/or contribute to) msiinv.

Comment: Yep, I'll keep an eye on it periodically.

Answer (score 1):

What does that tool do? Does it list the component GUIDs from an MSI? If so, I've found the DARK tool from [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net) to do a pretty good job of telling me what's in an MSI.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Lipscombe. This does indeed appear to be what I needed.

Comment: WIX DARK tool is an alternative to msiinv.exe (which is closely related to OP's question so +1 from me). 

I'm not sure if DARK can output a list of desired GUIDs. msiinv.exe + PowerShell can create a pretty cool bulk msiexec.exe /x ... script. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/

Answer (score -1):

The tool msiinv.exe what it really does is just list the GUI of all your installed MSI packages. You can use a file as an output.

Then the MSI Inventory tool will provide the needed GUI in order to run "msiexec.exe /x {B3A02601-8FE9-4108-8E95-D94171A2F8C8}" and uninstall the desired package.

Thanks.

Faith.

Comment: This answer contains *what* msiinv.exe does (note GUI --> GUID). OP asked *where* to get msiinv.exe.